# I keep getting "Battle.java:11: error: illegal start of expression" Heelp

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to have two monsters fight and return a monster winner. And I attempterd to  include a while loop in which monsters hit each other

```
public class Bat{

    public static void main (String [] args){
        monster s1 = new monster ["cat"];
        monster s2 = new monster ["dog"];

        s1.Strength = 10;
        s2.Strenght = 98;
    }
    public fight(monster m1, monster m2){
        int m1 = s1;
        int m2 = s2;
        int attack = s1;
        int attack2 = s2;

        if (m1 >= m2)
            return m1;
        else if(m2 >= m1)
            return m2;

        while ( m1 > m2 || m2 > m1) { 
            s1.Damn(attack2);
            s2.Damn(attack);              
        } 
    }  
}
```

Comment: `new monster ["Demagorgon"];` isn't valid java, perhaps you meant `new monster ("Demagorgon");`. `public fightToDeath` is missing a return type, might pass as `public int fightToDeath`. Try to use an ide (visual studio code, intellij...), it shows you what's wrong and where, also makes proposals to fix it.

Comment: Also can format the code automatically btw

Comment: Please format the code and paste the code of Monster class as well.

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: This post does not contain a concrete question. Also the pasted code fragment does not even compile. Why is anyone putting effort in answering it, if OP is not putting any effort in asking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your problems is, that you give your function "fightToDeath" two objects of type "monster". That is ok so far.
But here it gets very wrong:

```
int m1 = s1;
```

You assigend a monster-object (that has been declared globally and is not the argument) to an integer. I don't know what you are trying to achieve but this might be correct for you:

```
int m1Strength = m1.getStrength();
int m2Strength = m2.getStrength();
```

In your code your arguments in "fightToDeath" would be instantly overwritten. The way I wrote it, you would use your monsters you gave as an argument and get their strength and assign this strength to a local integer.

EDIT:

See this code:

```
public class Battle{

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Monster s1 = new Monster("Demorgogon", 10);
        Monster s2 = new Monster("Godzilla", 98);

        fightToDeath(s1, s2);
    }

    public static void fightToDeath(Monster m1, Monster m2){
        int m1Strength = m1.getStrength();
        int m2Strength = m2.getStrength();
        int attack = 5;
        int attack2 = 2;          

        while (m1Strength > 0 && m2Strength > 0) {
            m1.oof(attack2);
            m1Strength -= attack2;
            m2.oof(attack);
            m2Strength -= attack;
        }

        if(m1.getStrength() == 0){
            System.out.println("Winner is: " + m2.getName() + " with " + 
                         m2.getStrength() + " live left!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Winner is: " + m1.getName() + " with " + 
                         m1.getStrength() + " live left!");
        }
    }
}


public class Monster{
    int strength;
    String name;

    public Monster(String name, int strength){
        this.name = name;
        this.strength = strength;
    }

    public void setStrength(int newStrength){
        this.strength = newStrength;
    }

    public int getStrength(){
        return this.strength;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void oof(int attackValue){
        this.strength -= attackValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a brace closing the main method as well as around the if/else blocks.